# Anyone has integrated Swagger UI with Kraken D? In the community version there is no such option available

Tags: swagger, krakend

As the krakend.json is not of the type which swagger understands.Following error occurs:

*Error: Document must be valid OpenAPI 3.0.0 definition*

Is there any alternate way to generate documentation for krakenD

Answer (score 2):

Generating both KrakenD configuration and OpenAPI documentation is possible, but...

- You should precisely define your use case:

  - Do you want to generate `krakend.json` config from OpenAPI just as `no-op` proxy? (see [an example script](https://github.com/devopsfaith/krakendesigner/issues/94#issuecomment-845839140))
  - Are you willing to adopt another (custom) format? (see [openapi2krakend](https://github.com/okhuz/openapi2krakend))
  - Do you want to generate OpenAPI documentation from KrakenD config? If so, do you need just a list of endpoints or do you want also to have defined descriptions, examples and types (!) in one file?
- You should (at least try to) write the script to generate the configuration by yourself to suit your needs.
- Consider a usage of KrakenD Studio that has the [OpenAPI generator](https://www.krakend.io/docs/enterprise/endpoints/openapi/) plugin.

It can look like a good idea, but the devil is in the details and you should analyse your requirements because these two files have totally different purposes. I can only suggest you write such a transformation script ([as I did](https://github.com/devopsfaith/krakendesigner/issues/94#issuecomment-984357844)) which should be like "5 minutes of work" and then go to the deep.

---

Edit: We have selected a subset of KrakendD features and implemented our own configuration generator (from OAS). We use `tags` with a custom `route-to/` prefix for metadata, a definition could look like this:

```
  /coupons/{id}:
    get:
      tags:
        - Coupons
        - route-to/path=/coupons/{id}/detail
        - route-to/backend=GET|http://coupons.content
        - route-to/flags=jwt_validation
```